# How to properly bend leads of box-type film capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, pcb, pcb-design, passive-components

How to properly bend leads of film capacitor (radial type), mounted horizontally? (PCB height limitation) I need to bend leads safely, with normal bend radius, to avoid cracks in the resin or disconnection of the lead wires from the internal element.

[image: capacitor]

Comment: place your thumb at the connection between the cap and the lead wire, use as lever and pull with your index finger

Comment: The photo appears to be of a box-type film capacitor, not a ceramic capacitor.

Comment: Yes, you're right, its box type film capacitor.

Comment: Large-area flat side against the PCB? Be aware that *one of those leads* is connected to outside foil...which will capacitively-couple to any PCB traces underneath. Not much capacitance, but might cause problems. If one lead is grounded, or is attached to a low-impedance point, make it the outside-foil lead. And consider mechanically stabilizing a big capacitor to PCB.

Comment: @glen_geek It's low frequency circuit, the purpose of this capacitor is to control the maximum current flowing through the circuit.(capacitive transformerless power supply) Nominal is 1µF/250V class X2, the smallest one I find is Kemet  R46KN410040P1M. 1.043" L x 0.335" W (26.50mm x 8.50mm) It should be mounted horizontally, because PCB have mounting height limitation, must not exceed 9mm. In fact, I need a thinner one, but I haven't found.

Answer (score 4):

NASA recommendations are that you support the lead **on the component body** side (for example, with needle-nose pliers) and make equal bends at least two lead-diameters from the body. In this case, the 'body' would be the limits of the epoxy fill in the bottom.

So, grab the lead with the pliers at least two lead diameters from the body (there should be a visible gap between the epoxy and the pliers) and bend the lead with your finger or another tool. That's it. Nothing touches the component body while you are doing the bend.

Of course you can usually get away with being a lot more sloppy, but that's the proper way to do it.

Edit: as @Austris mentions, you can follow a standard. NASA has now folded their standards into IPC international standards as J-STD-001.

Comment: Thanks, clear and comprehensive.

Answer (score 3):

I would have commented on the great answer but my reputation doesn't allow it. :D If you want to be precise and follow best practices on your projects always follow IPC standard eg. IPC-A-610-F.

Comment: which particular paragraph describes this? Reference to a general standards document without specifying a specific point is useless.

Comment: Well it has a table of contents so I think the guy will be able to find it by himself easily.

Comment: this is useless and pointless suggestion.

Comment: Hello, I didn't want to point in the direction of the standard, since it should be purchased, but here you can find a draft version I guess: [link](https://slidex.tips/download/ipc-a-610-f-acceptability-of-electronic-assemblies-2). The section you are looking for is 7.1.2. There are also full versions of the document available, including pictures.